# WordPress - archive side list not linking correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have a post page, which is index.php.

On here, I have this piece of code:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

This displays the months that posts have been made. But for some bizzare reason, when I click on any of these months, It just goes to another random page, for example my about page?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seemed to be working, for example - If i hover over July 2015, I get /2015/07/

Comment: Also, it only seems to be certain months that go to the complete wrong page?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?
This has really stumped me.